# How to set attribute into NavParams for update url path in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

For example, show the value of the radio buttons selected in the URL.

URL: [domain]/selector/:value

```
@IonicPage({
  name: 'selector',
  section: 'selector/:value'
})
@Component({
  template: `
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="selector">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>First</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="first" checked></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Second</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="second"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
  `
})
class SelectorComponent {
  private _value;
  get selector() {
    return this._value;
  }
  set value(value) {
    this._value = value;
    //set :value in url equals current value
  }
}
```

Now, when user switches the button, he should see new :value in the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Ionic Page dynamic links](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/#dynamic-links). Add the `@IonicPage()` decorator on top of your component and specify a segment with your dynamic value.

```
@IonicPage({
  name: 'detail-page',
  segment: 'selector/:value'
})
```

And then you can push the page like this, passing your dynamic value as a navParam.

```
this.navCtrl.push('detail-page', {
  'value': detailInfo.value
})
```

Comment: You do not understand the question. I talked about using one component, not about creating other pages by adding to the stack. The user should see the changes in the address bar when the value is selected and still remain on the same page.

Comment: Some more clarifications on the question would have helped understand your problem better. From what I know, updating url without reloading is possible in browsers with the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API), but I don't think it is possible in Ionic yet.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible as of version 3.6

You can do this:

```
window.history.replaceState('', '', '#/selector/' + value); 

// optionally update navCtrl data
this.navCtrl.getActive().data.radioValue = value;
```